# Hibernate envers is not updating manually added columns in REVINFO with annotation

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am using plain java to hibernate standalone application with Hibernate Envers for getting updates of changes made in table's columns, I am using sql server as my Database, and I am new in envers.

Here is my "CustomRevisionEntity.java"

```
@Entity
@AuditTable("REVINFO")
@RevisionEntity(CustomRevisionListener.class)
public class CustomRevisionEntity {

@Column (name = "USERNAME", length = 50)
private String username;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@RevisionNumber
@Column (name = "REV", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column (name = "REVTSTMP", nullable = false, length = 15)
@RevisionTimestamp
private Date timestamp;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}
public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
}
```

CustomRevisionListener.java

```
public class CustomRevisionListener implements RevisionListener {
public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
    CustomRevisionEntity revision = (CustomRevisionEntity) revisionEntity ;
    String userName = Hibernate_Connection.getloggedUser();
    revision.setUsername(userName);
}
}
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;instance=SQLEXPRESS_2012;DatabaseName=ETS_V11_DEV;integratedSecurity=true</property> -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property> -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping class= "Domain_hibernate_SQLServer.Domain"/>
    <mapping class= "Domain_hibernate_SQLServer.CustomRevisionEntity"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Problem: While using hbm.xml file then it is adding value on username column,
but while I am using Annotation for getting value that time is taking null value as it is not recognizing extra column property that I have added, but
While using annotation, its inserting null values in username columns

It is taking values like this with annotation while seeing sql code on console

```
/* insert org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity
    */ insert 
    into
        REVINFO
        (REVTSTMP) 
    values
        (?)
```

Table has only 3 columns, 1 is REV, i.e, autoincrement, 2nd is REVTSTMP, nd 3rd is USERNAME, and Its not taking username,
What I am missing, If you need more information then please comment

Comment: fixed, Silly Mistake, I had a problem with cfg.xml DOCTYPE

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from your annotation config so can post your hbm.xml file and the class used for the anotation config?

Comment: Thank u for rplying vvs. I have added "hibernate.cfg.xml" file in the above code. And though I am using Annotation so no need to create "hbm.xml" file. Is there any issue in this file